# Do you use the word 'readers' when talking about a play?

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a literature analysis essay on a play and was wondering which word I would use to describe the people viewing/reading the play.

I'm used to the word reader(s) as I have wrote essays for stories and novels but was unsure if this needed to be swapped for a word like viewer when writing about a play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You read a script and watch or attend a performance.  You and your fellow readers are the readership.  You and your fellow attendees are the audience.

Comment: The way a written play looks on the page and the way it sounds when pronounced are vastly different. Be specific whether you're talking about readers, performers, or audience.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the word "Audience" because audience could be somebody viewing, or reading the play

Comment: Would you really think of yourself as the audience if you're sitting at home reading a play?

Comment: Hi, this would benefit from a source or citation.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the EL&U [help].

Comment: Hi Nyanza, this has already been suggested in the existing answer. Please take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with this platform. You can upvote answers you agree with or find useful. Welcome to ELU!